# Amazon S3 copyObject - File not visible in bucket

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to copy object using Amazon s3 copyObject() method.

Following is the code:

```
$copied = $s3->copyObject(array(
                            'Bucket' => $this->bucket,
                            'CopySource' => urlencode($this->bucket .'/'.$source_file),
                            'Key' => $this->dir.$jduid.'/'.$new_file
                            ));
```

This method seems to be working fine. 
If I am printing the result of copyObject I am getting :

```
Guzzle\Service\Resource\Model Object
(
[structure:protected] => 
[data:protected] => Array
    (
        [LastModified] => 2016-10-26T07:32:34.373Z
        [ETag] => "08fa3106a8b7839b803f4ddf65b56919"
        [Expiration] => 
        [CopySourceVersionId] => 
        [ServerSideEncryption] => 
        [SSECustomerAlgorithm] => 
        [SSECustomerKeyMD5] => 
        [SSEKMSKeyId] => 
        [RequestCharged] => 
        [RequestId] => c0a80b5b:1558b420117:3e7c6:9a9
    )

)
```

But I am not able to find the new copied file in the bucket. Any suggestion.

Comment: `'Key' => $this->dir.$jduid.'/'.$new_file` -- put this into a variable before assigning it to `Key` and log it.  That should give you some idea of what might be going wrong.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I tried that. But the problem remains the same.

Comment: Maybe show us what you see when you do that?  The key, for example, should not have a leading or trailing slash, or any adjacent slashes.  With some libraries, in some cases, doing this can result in creating object that exists, but is invisible in the S3 console.